Why don't people reference source-code?
Why do people so rarely reference source-code when responding to questions. It's like giving lemonade to people looking for lemons.

Probably because questions hardly ever ask for source code, or often when they do, the requested code doesn't exist yet?

Whoever downvoted please explain why you did so, so that the question can be improved.
